# Which App should we use for Payment in Paypal?

Tags: android, cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a phonegap app and it has 2 variables to set PayPalEnvironmentProduction & PayPalEnvironmentSandbox in paypal.js file.

I logged in to my developer.paypal.com account and there i can see "v.zero SDK" & "REST API apps" on URL : https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ .

I am not sure which values should I put for both my variables PayPalEnvironmentProduction & PayPalEnvironmentSandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 3 APIs you can pull here. There is an NVP/SOAP as well. So the question I have is What APIs are used in the paypal.js file?

If you see REST APIs denoted by Client/Secret (PayPal)(V.0 is for BrainTree APIs) then you'll want to apply for REST APIs; if you see APP ID with user password and digital signature you'll want to use/apply for the [NVP/SOAP APIs](http://prntscr.com/brkg0r). Hopefully this helps, let me know if you have more questions as I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I am not sure how to find what APIs are used in the paypal.js file? can you pls tell me.

Comment: In my paypal.js file I have a variable like below

`code`

var clientIDs = {
       "PayPalEnvironmentProduction": "YOUR_PRODUCTION_CLIENT_ID",
       "PayPalEnvironmentSandbox": "YOUR_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID"
     };

Comment: Ok. Then you'll want to use the REST APIs and it's accessible in your developer account / dashboard / My APPs/ REST APP <-- create one first, then you'll be given the sandbox keys. Here is a doc that may help in the flow of your developer portal in applying http://geekmechanics.weebly.com/paypal-rest/live-rest-api